# Pass parameters on redirection internally

Tags: php, laravel

I have an endpoint which is doing something (`facade-endpoint`), and then redirecting to another endpoint (`endpoint`) in the same application. What I'm trying to do here is I want to pass few parameters on redirection, but I don't want to allow others to pass them when they call the second endpoint directly.

For example:

```
public function facadeEndpoint(FacadeEndpointRequest $request)
{
  $var1 = SomeClass::doSomething();
  $var2 = SomeClass::doSomethingElse();

  $request = Request::create('endpoint', 'GET');
  return app()->handle($request); // I want to pass $var1 and $var2 here, so that they don't get recalculated once again after the redirection
}

public function endpoint(EndpointRequest $request)
{
  $var1 = SomeClass::doSomething();
  $var2 = SomeClass::doSomethingElse(); // If the request came from facade-endpoint, I want to use passed values instead of calling SomeClass functions again

  // do something...
}
```

However as I mentioned, I don't want people to be able to pass `$var1` or `$var2` to the request directly - they should only be calculated in the application.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can pass the data in the session or in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add an additional parameter to signal that it came from facade endpoint.

```
$request = Request::create('endpoint', 'GET', ['internal' => true]);
```

Then when you receive request in your endpoint you can check whether it exists.

```
if ($request->has('internal')) {
  // from facade endpoint
} else {
  // called directly
}
```

The problem with this being a GET request is that parameters will be present in the url.